# Select2 jquery quitar mensaje "please enter 1 or more characters en select2"

Tags: javascript, jquery, select2

Quiero quitar ese mensaje, ¿alguna forma?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui el html:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí el jquery:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te recomiendo que coloques el HTML que genera este código. Para poder apoyar a la causa, es un poco mas complicado imaginar la estructura.

Comment: intenta adicionando esta esta opción `inputTooShort: ""` aunque creo que no sera posible cambiarlo amenos que elimines la linea de mensaje del archivo js

Comment: @AlfonsoCarrasco Actualizado...

Comment: eso del inputTooShort: "" no funciona.

Comment: @JuanGlezz funciono. Saludos.

Comment: @EvolutionxD lo de modificar el archivo no es la solución mas correcta porque no cumple con ciertos criterios del autor así que puedes intentar hacer también lo que te dejo como  respuesta Wilfredo ya que podría ser lo mejor

Answer (score 3):

Lo puedes hacer colocando:

```
minimumInputLength: 2,
formatInputTooShort: "",
```

Adicionalemente podrías hacerle una sobrecarga:

```
minimumInputLength: 1,
            formatInputTooShort: function () {
                return "Este es mi mensaje";
            },
```

Answer (score 0):

Sobreescribe la salida del mensaje usando:

```
  formatInputTooShort: function () {
    return "";
  }
```

Aqui dejo un jsfiddle funcional: https://jsfiddle.net/dya6odt9/

Answer (score 0):

**Esto ha cambiado en la versión 4.0:**

```
language: {
  inputTooShort: function () {
    return 'Mi mensaje.';
  }
}
```

---

Ver [formatInputTooShort property not working #4252](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/4252):

> *kevin-brown commented on 18 Mar 2016:*
>
> Internationalization is one of the many things that changed in Select2
>   4.0.0.
>
> https://github.com/select2/select2/releases/tag/4.0.0-beta.1
>
> You can now specify it using language.inputTooShort.
>
> https://jsfiddle.net/86t7term/

---

[Página de lanzamiento:](https://github.com/select2/select2/releases/tag/4.0.0-beta.1)

> ## Breaking changes
>
> [...]
>
> ### Renamed options
>
> [...]
>
> **Internationalization**
>
> ```
> formatNoMatches -> language.noMatches
> formatSearching -> language.searching
> formatInputTooShort -> language.inputTooShort
> formatInputTooLong -> language.inputTooLong
> formatAjaxError -> language.errorLoading
> formatLoading -> language.loadingMore
> formatSelectionTooBig -> language.maximumSelected
> ```

Comment: Podrías dar mas detalles respecto al código. E intenta evitar link, los links con el tiempo se rompen :)